# He configurado el envío de un formulario pero me sale todo el informe en la confirmación

Tags: php

He configurado el envío del formulario con el siguiente código. Todo funciona bien desde mi entorno local, llegan los correos, pero al enviarlo aparece toda la retahíla de información del proceso y sólo quiero que aparezca que el email ha sido enviado. Pongo pantallazo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'pauladomingoweb@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '*******';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('pauladomingoweb@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('pauladomingoweb@gmail.com');     // Add a recipient
   
  

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = "Nombre:".$nombre."\r\n Email: ".$email."\r\n Telefono: ".$telefono."Mensaje:".$mensaje."\r\n";
 

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes puesto el debug a 2.

Quita esta línea (o ponla a 0)

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

[Fuente](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging)

Comment: Hola!! Gracias, ahora sí.